# Encouragement to write more answers

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, data-explorer

I wrote [this Data Explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/120944#graph) to show the average answer-accept rate vs the number of answers a user has written, minus the top power-users (who don't accurately represent the average user). Results:

[image]

There aren't too many users out there with >2000 answers written, so there is noise out there.

This says that "When you write more answers, you get better at it!" Or, it could say "Users who had a bad time with their first few answers don't bother coming back to SO."

I think this is great encouragement for users with <500 answers to keep writing more answers! Right now I have 419 answers and an accepted-answer rate of 32.75%, pretty close to the average per the graph.

Higher granularity for Under-500-answers:

[image]

Log-base-2 x-axis:

[image]

Comment: It raises more questions than it provides answers really.

Comment: Just because I'm below the average, does that still mean that I have a chance at being accepted by the community?

Comment: @ChrisForrence No. Your account will be deleted in 3....2....

Comment: Aw drat. Still, an interesting query @Joe!

Comment: Yes, @bill  you really do: [here's a per user query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/120955/your-answer-stats)... I have double :-)

Comment: Where do you want to take this discussion though @JoeFrambach? I mean, the data requires a lot more refinement and filtering to say anything sensible. What are you hoping to get out of this? What is the input you're looking for?

Comment: I guess I was kinda hoping you had some way of linking it back into [Are unanswered questions a problem yet?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143113/are-unanswered-questions-a-problem-yet/143137#143137). Yes, you're almost certainly right but there has to be somewhere to go from here... do you have any ideas?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn You just had to share that with the rest of us, didn't you? Bragging..... ;)

Comment: @ben The linked post says "What seems certain though is that Stack Overflow needs to find a way of converting question askers into question answerers. Without flooding the place with crap answers.". I think this query could show that the "flood of crap" concern isn't something we should worry about unless it actually happens.

Comment: @JoeFrambach Unless your data simply means that those who answer a lot by default, also are those who really have the answers. In which case encouraging users to answer more would not necessarily be so productive.

Comment: I concede that point. It's all very tautological.

Comment: But don't you answer only when you have an answer. I don't... Wait what?

Comment: @doubleDown the problem arises when someone has a correct answer but cannot articulate it well enough without lots of practice. Another answerer later on will get the Accept. This should encourage that type of user to answer more questions. Whether or not this is actually a problem, well, who knows.

Comment: Looks like I am *dead on* the average for my answer count. Oh, wait, I may be in a slot of 1.. Perhaps you need to calculate the average over a larger range instead? Or pick logarithmic ranges; the higher the number of answers given, the bigger the slot.

Comment: Updated with a log-base-2 x-axis. Awesome.