# Where do people announce interesting uses of Stack Exchange data?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, data-explorer

I've been working on what I think is an interesting mashup of Stack-Exchange-provided data from the data dumps with another data source.  Where should I announce it when I'm ready for people to try it out?

**Edit:**
A deleted answer helpfully pointed out [stackapps.com](https://stackapps.com/), but [the tour page](https://stackapps.com/tour) says:

> Lots of topics are fair game, as long as they are about the Stack
>   Exchange API, applications that use the Stack Exchange API, or scripts
>   that work on the Stack Exchange network of websites.

It looks like you can [promote an application](https://stackapps.com/questions/7/how-to-list-your-application-library-wrapper-script-here) in a question there, but I'm not that refers to apps that only use the static data dump and not the API.

Answer (score 1):

After digging around on stackapps.com, I found a [data-dump tag](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/data-dump) that people use to announce applications using the dumps.  So stackapps.com appears to be the right place.

Comment: Most of them are bugs and requests for help. Not sure if it is an announcement board.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably announce it through your own channels: blog, twitter, etc.

If there is a question or discussion regarding that data that is on-topic for Meta SE, then you could post it here.

Take a look at this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143113/are-unanswered-questions-a-problem-yet) (the first I found, so no measure for 'the best') that uses the data and comes up with a useful discussion.